# Compose set color of MaterialDialogButtons?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have imported a date picker library to my compose app and one of the arguments is MaterialDialogButton. The button works fine but it's purple and I don't know how to change the color. I've tried adding a AlertDialogTheme to my theme but it does nothing. I followed this article but nothing happens, any tips?
https://lcdsmao.medium.com/material-design-custom-alert-dialog-5a9cab3ade11

[image: App]

For the button color to change

Comment: If you're using Compose Material3, do note that a [`DatePickerDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#DatePickerDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerColors,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function1)) composable [was introduced in 1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0).

Comment: Ah shit, I'll have to look into that. I'm quite noob at android so I don't even know what I'm using :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialDialog(
  dialogState = timeDialogState,
  buttons = {
    positiveButton(
      text = "Ok",
      textStyle = TextStyle(
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
      )
    ) {

    }
    negativeButton(
      text = "Cancel",
      textStyle = TextStyle(
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.